# Unit Test Adapter threw exception: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. CodedUI with Test Manager

Tags: c#, testing, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

When I'm trying to run CodedUI test from Microsoft Test Manager 2015 i get Error:

"Unit Test Adapter threw exception: Unable to load one or more of the requested types"

[image]

I start having this problem after switching from VS2013 to VS2015.
Tried to fix this by changing test adapters but it did't worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you upgraded to VS2015 the references to the CodedUI libraries were updated to the newest version. Likely you are running 2013 Test Agents which cant load the newer assemblies.

You have to rebind them at runtime in your app.config. However, when you do this, VS2015 will have trouble loading the older libraries, you will have to either comment out that part of the config or some other way. We use a powershell script to automatically uncomment that part on our build server so what gets deployed to the agents is the correct config.

You need to add the following to the app.config:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WindowsStore.CodedUITestFramework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WindowsStore.UITest.Common" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WindowsStore.UITest.Extension" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.ExtensionUtilities" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WindowsStore.UITesting" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.1.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WindowsStore.UITest.Playback" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>


<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WindowsStore.UITest.Framework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="UiaComWrapper.WindowsStore" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="UiaComWrapper" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```